# How to set the value of count to zero while count has some integer value init in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem, the data fetched through coredata and then count has the no of records in it. When the application runs first time the value of count is zero, once the record fetched, the value of count is equal to no. of records. Now I want to reset the value of count to zero. need your kind suggestion.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest  fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Article"];
NSUInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if(count == 0)
    {
     NSArray *array = [json valueForKey:@"Artikler"];
     for(id key in array){
     Article *article = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Article" inManagedObjectContext:context];
     article.articleId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[key valueForKey:@"Id"]intValue]];       
            if([key valueForKey:@"Name"]== [NSNull null])
                article.name = @"Tittel";
            else
                article.name = [key valueForKey:@"Name"];
}}
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you want or what is going on? Resetting the value of 'count' to zero will give you answers like: `count=0;`. Perhaps you want the table to be cleared on restart? Or a commit being rolled back? Or a new data store to be created?

Answer (score 0):

**This is Simple Logic for you.**

Add all data in `NSMutableArray`

If you want to count number of record in your Array then write `myArray.count` this return number of record that are fetched from coreData by you.

and If You want to **reset Zero value** the then write following code

```
if(myAraay.count > 0)
  [myArray removeAllObjects];
```

This code remove all data from array so your array has no value.

Then when you write `myArray.count` then it give **Zero** value.

Comment: `count` is a method. It should be called as a method: `[myAraay count]`. BTW. Do you have a reason to check count before clearing the mutable array. It would work without that check. A performance gain?